# ASP .net default login control very slow (Visual Studio template)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, visual-studio-2013, login-control

I have looked at other post on same subject, but they were either unanswered or old (.Net 2.0).

Very simply: in Visual Studio 2013, I create a Web app (or a Web site, same results) : ASP.NET Web Form template. I.e. this uses .Net 4.5.

It comes with Login Control. I am hosted on Windows Azure and have successfully changed the connection string to access Azure database. Login and register work fine. However, when I click on Login, Register, or Manage, it is really slow (20+ seconds).
I suspect this might be related to the Membership provider. However, there is no membership provider in the template and it works without it, which might be because it uses Universal Membership.

The Database is fine: I checked it. It has been created, but it is still slow. When I first click on "Hello, Serge!:" it goes to the Manage.aspx page: it takes 20 sec. But the second time I click on the same "Hello, Serge!" it only takes 2 sec.

How to increase speed? 
Is the slowliness related with Membership provider, accessing Database or downloading the huge EntityFramework.dll (5mb)?

Serge

Comment: The entity framework dll won't be downloaded on the client PCs. Have you checked your database?

Comment: The app should be using the new ASP.NET Identity framework. I've used it quite a bit on Azure Web Sites and it hasn't been slow. There's a delay of a few seconds at the very first time it's running because EF is creating the database tables, but it should be fast after that.

Comment: The Database is fine: I checked it. It has been created, but it is still slow. When I click on "Hello, Serge!:" it goes to the Manage.aspx page: it takes 20 sec. But the second time I click on the same "Hello, Serge!" it only takes 2 sec.